# Gaussian pythogrean triples

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

So there are ways to generate all the Pythagorean triples, is there any similar process to find all the Gaussian Pythagorean triples?

Comment: A first thought: the parametrisation $(u^2-v^2, 2uv, u^2+v^2)$ still generates Pythagorean triples in the Gaussian integers (in fact, it does in any commutative ring). Maybe it still generates all of them?

Comment: See [Primitive Pythagorean Triples of Gaussian Integers](https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/primitive-pythagorean-triples-of-gaussian-integers).